# What should I do in case I have dominant feature in XGB model?

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost, feature-selection, information-gain

I've recently faced a "strange" observation in my dataset. After XGB modeling with 20 features I plot top 10 features with the highest gain values. Result is shown below:

```
F1         140027.061202
F2          11242.470370
F3           9957.161039
F4           9677.070632
F5           7103.275865
F6           4691.814929
F7           4030.730915
F8           2775.235616
F9           2384.573760
F10          2328.680871
```

As you can see **F1** dominates with gain compared to all other features (12x more gain than F2). I verified the results on test set, model is not overfitting and it gives a decent results (comparing to my figures of merit):

```
F1-score: 0.739812237993 
Accuracy: 0.839632893701 
Precision: 0.63759578607
Recall: 0.881059718486
```

Based on these results is it correct to conclude that F1 feature is enough for building a model?

In order to prove this, I re-run the modeling with the same parameters, but now having F1 as a standalone feature. Results are just slightly worse than previous (and no over-fit):

```
F1-score: 0.710906846703 
Accuracy: 0.819880412472 
Precision: 0.607953806173
Recall: 0.85583736242
```

My XGB parameters are super simple in both cases:

```
alg = XGBRegressor( 
    n_estimators=200,
    max_depth=5,
    objective='binary:logistic', 
    seed=27,
)

# Fit the algorithm on the data
metric = 'map'
alg.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric=metric)
```

After I exclude feature F1 and re-fit the model I get the similar verification metrics (slightly worse) but in that case feature F3 becomes "dominant" with a really high gain ~ 10000 while feature F2 is the next one with gain value ~ 10000.

1. Is there any technique to boost other features and increase the accuracy (or F1-score) by applying certain transformations on F1?
2. Is there any way to equalize features gain and improve the model?
3. Should I try to "collect" more features that can have comparable gain as F1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding and tuning additional parameters and using grid search to find the optimal combination? To prevent over fitting I can suggest adding:

- colsample_bytree: subsample ratio of columns when constructing each tree
- subsample: Subsample ratio of the training instances
- min_child_weight: prevent learning relations highly specific to the particular sample

Since you are using XGBRegressor, try modifying the objective function. I can also suggest monitoring the validation and training loss when building the trees.

[Reference documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) ! Yes, I did try to tune those parameters as well, and the result remains mostly unchanged, in terms of metrics and in terms of feature importance. 

I did not try to run any optimization (grid search) because I was not sure if this will help. Also, are you suggesting that this model is overfitting? I check metrics results both on train and test data and they r more or less the same ... 

I will def. try to monitor validation/training loss and check if something is suspicious there.